# How to execute java functions/script in PHP

Tags: java, php, apache, tomcat, bridge

I have a system which is implemented using PHP(Joomla). Now the client wants to integrate a SMS gateway. Unfortunately SMS gateway does not supoort PHP. It's written in Java and All the examples are written in JAVA.

I'm supposed to include `webservices‐rt.jar` to my program and run a example script as below.

```
lk.mobitel.esms.User user = new lk.mobitel.esms.User (); user.setUsername(“TestUser”);
user.setPassword(“Password”);
lk.mobitel.esms.test.ServiceTest st = new lk.mobitel.esms.test.ServiceTest (); 
System.out.println(st.testService(u));
```

According to my knowledge I can run a `.jar` as below using PHP

```
<?php exec("java -jar filename.jar arguments",$output); ?>
```

How can I run a JAVA script like above in PHP? Is it possible? Is there a way to bridge PHP and JAVA? What I want is to run JAVA in PHP else I would say communicate between these two.

Comment: Whats wrong with running the JAR as shown?

Comment: I have an Apache server and PHP system. what I want is to run JAVA in PHP else I would say communicate between these two.

Comment: You could always read through the Java, work out what it's doing and where it posts to and recreate the post using cURL in PHP? Wireshark is pretty good for capturing HTTP traffic..?

Which SMS Gateway are you using? I work for www.txtNation.com and we could help you here!

Comment: This is a gateway which is selected by client so I have to use this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did this, but PHP Manual gave a link for PHP-Java Bridge for PHP5 as [PHP/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/). If it is what you are looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to combine PHP and Java in the same script and have them executed in one run.

Your `exec` approach is the way to go, if you are approaching from PHP. But you should rather use [passthru](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.passthru.php) as exec does not return anything. With passthru you can get the shell response of your java command and act accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a way to bridge PHP and JAVA? What I want is to run JAVA in PHP else I would say communicate between these two.**

Simple answer:

Bridge using data-exchange layer. :)

Hint (in super simple language): My favorite webservice uses PERL to process their scripts and I fetch them using XML.
Groupon is made on RoR but, I happily get tweets, thanks to their API which outputs a JSON.

Simple? :)