# Java/PHP Bridge and using Curl

Tags: java, php

Has anyone got experience of using PHP/Java Bridge?
From what I can gather it enables PHP scripts on a Java server and vice versa.

My problem is I need to do PHP Calls (using curl) on a Tomcat JSP based server.

I am trying to access if Java/PHP Bridge will solve the problems, and if I can use PHP curl with it.

Any ideas/comments very welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953932/how-to-execute-java-functions-script-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Since I can not comment, I will use this space to put forward my idea (might not be the answer).

Using php curl to execute services or fetch (JSON)data from tomcat server is a better approach in terms of maintainability.
By the way, why is curl a problem?

Comment: I need to access a service with curl using pem certs. The documentation offers curl as a prefered method. Java offers libcurl and http client both seem to be complex to set up. The problem I have is the java server is not under my control I was looking for a solution that could be deloyed in a web application (.war) with minimal effect on server.

Comment: Accessing secure services using php curl with pem certificates (no java): [Using cURL in PHP to access HTTPS (SSL/TLS) protected sites] (http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/). In case you decide to write a java wrapper then you may go through following : [How to verify PEM format certificate in Java] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342343/how-to-verify-pem-format-certificate-in-java).